# Loading New Data without purging the Old data in tables in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, migration, loading

I have a Primary SQL Server and Secondary SQL server. 
Primary SQL server is configured to maintain only 90 days of data. On 91st day, it will remove the oldest one days data to add new days data.

My requirement is to set the Secondary SQL server to have the complete data of 90 days and from 91st day onwards keep appending the new data.

Answer (score 1):

Look at [tables partitioning](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190787.aspx). I  made such architecture (fill free to ask me details), workflow is folowing:

For example we have table `t1` in primary server and the same in secondary server.

1. Swich 91 section from `t1` to `t1_temp`
2. Load this section to secondery server with ETL(SSIS) into table `t1_buffer`
3. Switch partition from `t1_buffer` to `t1` on the secondary server

next time you will do the same workflow with 92 section.

**Note:** all table `t1` (primary), `t1_temp`, `t1_buffer`, `t1`(secondary) should be partitioned with the same [partition function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms187802.aspx).